# Create custom rounded corner on an image using only CSS

Tags: css

Looking for a smart way to use **CSS only** to apply a **left rounded corner** to an image. Using the standard CSS border radius property isn't suitable as it's too round. The best I could come up with is positioning an SVG image of the round effect on top of the image - not ideal as this can sometimes "flicker in" on page load.

```
.banner {background:hotpink}

.img-wrap:before {
content: "";
background: url(img/rounded-corner-left.svg) no-repeat;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
display: block;
background-size: contain;
height: 100%;
background-position: top left;
z-index: 2;
}
```

[image]

Using this border-radius setting, provided in an answer, the effect is too rounded at the top of the image.

```
border-radius: 20% 0 0 0 / 100% 0 0 0;
```

[image]

Comment: So something like `border-radius: 20% 0 0 0 / 100% 0 0 0;` is not acceptable? Look at [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) and try something with that.

Comment: I think I jumped the gun - unfortunately, it is still too rounded at the top using border radius (I've updated the question with the border radius applied on the image).

Answer (score 1):

The **border-top-left-radius** property defines the radius of the top-left corner.
or change the other values like : right, left, bottom ...

Example :

```
border-radius: 120px 20px 120px 20px;
border-radius: 0 50% 50% 50%;
border-radius: 40px 40px 0 0; // example this one is rounded top left corner 
only
```

Just play with the values to try it and see yourself how it suits the best or the specifics you may have.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how round you want the left side to be so the  code snippet below shows how to make the left side 100% round:

```css
.image-with-rounded-corner-on-the-left {
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=667&q=80" alt="enter image description here" class="image-with-rounded-corner-on-the-left">
```

And below is how you make it 10% round:

```css
.image-with-rounded-corner-on-the-left {
  border-top-left-radius: 10%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=667&q=80" alt="enter image description here" class="image-with-rounded-corner-on-the-left">
```

You can adjust how round you want to make the left border percentage wise in the lines

```
border-top-left-radius: [put percentage here];
border-bottom-left-radius: [put percentage here];
```

Comment: Thanks for the post! The problem with the example border radius percentage you've provided is that the radius eats into the image too much when it's a high value, or when it's a low value it's not "stretched" enough  (the only way I can best explain this desired effect is by looking at the example image in my question).